# xcode 6.1 Update linked frameworks

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I recently updated my development environment from XCode 5 to XCode 6. I also updated the architecture in Build Settings to "Standard architectures" to comply with [Apple's policy change](https://developer.apple.com/news/?id=10202014a) that is in effective from Feb 1.

However, After Building with the new settings, I get a bunch of `Apple Mach-O Linker Errors` which I believe is due to the references made to the external libraries, `MapView` & `Restkit`

I believe I need to update these dependencies to a 64-bit compliant version, but am unsure of how to go about it. This is how the "Build Phase" looks currently.(Notice : two dependencies being highlighted in Red).

[image: Screenshot from Xcode 6.1]

Will cloning a latest version of the libraries work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "Red" you're seeing there mean that Xcode isn't seeing the .a files.

First thing you should do is see if you actually have them.  If you do, drag the .a files into your project and then also copy them into that Build Phase to replace the "missing" .a files.

Next thing you need to do is make certain the .a files you have are 64-bit compatible.  You'll find out pretty quick when you attempt to compile and you see "`x86_64`" related missing symbol errors in your build log.  If that happens, yes you should clone new versions of those libraries, build them and then copy the resulting .a libraries into your own project.

Comment: > First thing you should do is see if you actually have them. 
How should I go about checking that, I just cloned the latest version of a library, RestKit, and dragged the .xcodeproject file of library in the current project. It still highlights the products of the package as Red. Screenshot : https://www.dropbox.com/s/etkmenoc57n5y32/Screenshot%202015-03-05%2014.19.00.png?dl=0